# Can I somehow connect my local .JSON database to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, json, heroku

I made a Node/Express app and it works fine with local .JSON storage. Recently I tried to push it on Heroku and just after a day I learned about Heroku restarting apps and not saving any app changes.

My whole app is made for saving in local .JSON file and I don't want change or rewrite everything. So I wonder if there's way to just somehow link the local file with external database.

Comment: "My whole app is made for saving in local .JSON file and i dont want change or rewrite everything"—a JSON file is not a database and I _strongly_ urge you to change your stance on this. But if you insist on continuing to use a file for this, Tim Nguyen's answer is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

If you need persistent storage, it's not best practice to write the code to a local JSON file. If you really want to use a json file, you could have your app read and write to an S3 bucket where your JSON file is stored.

Becareful of how often you need to read and write that file to the S3 bucket though, because this pattern won't handle large r/w load.